# FFMPEG No such filter: 'format=nv12|vaapi,hwupload'

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu

I'm on a AWS g4ad instance and I am trying to get hardware accelleration with the GPU to work. with ffmpeg. A base line test is this:

```
 ffmpeg -y -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -v info -thread_queue_size 10000  -i video.mp4 -c:v h264_vaapi -vf 'format=nv12|vaapi,hwupload' -crf 25 -tune zerolatency -g 120  -r 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset faster -maxrate 14000k -bufsize 14000k -strict -2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -af aresample=async=1 -acodec aac file_out.mp4
```

The above works, GPU is installed and working correctly. In my actual use case, I am grabbing the screen from an X11Grab, which works without the GPU and normal libx264 but fails when I add try to use h264_vaapi. The command I use is below:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -y -v info -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -r 60 -s 1920x1080 -thread_queue_size 10000 -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -thread_queue_size 10000 -i plug:bsnoop -acodec aac -strict -2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -af aresample=async=1 -c:v h264_vaapi -vf 'format=nv12|vaapi,hwupload' -preset faster -maxrate 14000k -bufsize 14000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -crf 25 -g 120 -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://[to_an_rtmp source]

And my output is this:

2022-11-14 02:08:30.928 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: ffmpeg version 5.1.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.sav1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
2022-11-14 02:08:30.928 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2~18.04.sav0)
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0ubuntu1~18.04.sav1.1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-lcms2 --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-sndio --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-crystalhd --enable-libmfx --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e --enable-shared
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: [x11grab @ 0x56155ee70ac0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0+0,0':
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   Duration: N/A, start: 1668391710.975066, bitrate: 3981312 kb/s
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1920x1080, 3981312 kb/s, 60 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Input #1, alsa, from 'plug:bsnoop':
2022-11-14 02:08:31.105 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   Duration: N/A, start: 1668391710.731953, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
2022-11-14 02:08:31.106 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
2022-11-14 02:08:31.106 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (rtmp://ingest.bingewave.com/live/ce98c9bb-78b0-4ee5-8a8e-af35160da695-broadcast?sign=1668996507-c340acfb5219383f660d41057a050de6) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
2022-11-14 02:08:31.106 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Codec AVOption preset (Encoding preset) specified for output file #0 (rtmp://ingest.bingewave.com/live/ce98c9bb-78b0-4ee5-8a8e-af35160da695-broadcast?sign=1668996507-c340acfb5219383f660d41057a050de6) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Codec AVOption tune (The metric that the encoder tunes for. Automatically chosen by the encoder by default) specified for output file #0 (rtmp://ingest.bingewave.com/live/ce98c9bb-78b0-4ee5-8a8e-af35160da695-broadcast?sign=1668996507-c340acfb5219383f660d41057a050de6) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Stream mapping:
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (h264_vaapi))
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42:   Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: [AVFilterGraph @ 0x56155ee5d880] No such filter: 'format=nv12|vaapi,hwupload'
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Error reinitializing filters!
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
2022-11-14 02:08:31.237 INFO: [557] LoggingUtils$Companion$OutputLogger$1.invoke$lambda-0#42: Conversion failed!
root@ip-172-31-90-180:~#
```

I see that is failing because No such filter: 'format=nv12|vaapi,hwupload', which I don't get when I run the other command. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around the filter expression

Comment: That worked....by why?!?!

Comment: I actually don't know how the base line test worked... FFmpeg cli parser takes the single-quoted string as a single entity. So, it was literally looking for a filter named `format=nv12|vaapi,hwupload` which obviously doesn't exist. Removing the quotes allowed the parser to take each filter separately. My guess with your base line test was whatever environment you're in must removed the quotes before sending the arguments to FFmpeg.